# Install Symfony without symfony/runtime and with old index.php

Tags: symfony

I am trying to add Symfony 5.4 to my legacy project. There is a pretty nice documentation on how to do this, but there's a big problem - the documentation assumes "normal" Symfony, but each time I try to install Symfony using their recommended way of `composer create-project`, I get a Symfony version with `symfony/runtime` - the big problem here, is that this version has a completely different `index.php`:

```
<?php

use App\Kernel;

require_once dirname(_DIR_).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';

return function (array $context) {
    return new Kernel($context['APP_ENV'], (bool) $context['APP_DEBUG']);
};
```

The documentation found [here](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/migration.html) is based on a completely different index file.

I did find that I can remove the runtime package, and just copy old index, and it works for the most part, but then you also have problems with `console.php` and I worry that if I go this route there will be more and more problems caused by my installation expecting `symfony/runtime` and me manually removing it's

I tried installing Symfony 5.3 as well as different patches of 5.4, all came with this installed, even though I did work on some 5.3 / 5.4 projects and had the old school `index.php` file.

Does anyone know how to currently install Symfony with the "old" `index.php`, `console.php` etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: The runtime stuff was added in [5.3](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-runtime-component).  I suppose you could go back to 5.2 but, as you say, that will probably just case more problems especially if you ever wanted to move to 6+.   I'm guessing your legacy project has modified the standard index.php?  Perhaps you could post the changes to your question and maybe a work around will be suggested.

Comment: @Cerad my legacy project is actually just CodeIgniter 3, so it does have it's own `index.php`, routing etc. and I want to minimize changes to that to avoid breaking anything.

I think if it was added in 5.3, then installing 5.2 and updating to 5.4 might be a solution and it should work out of the box - I will try that tomorrow and update my post accordingly.

Thank you.

Comment: Good luck but CI does not really overlap with Symfony in any meaningful way.  The default Symfony index.php does very little.  You are not going to have much luck modifying it to match CI.

Comment: @Cerad what I did was copy contents of Symfony `index.php` to the beginning of CI `index.php` which is still the "front controller". If Symfony has a non 404 response I exit, if it has a 404, then I just do nothing, and CI index logic works. This seems like it's working but I haven't set up any routes on Symfony yet.

EDIT: I did install Symfony 5.2 and just updated it to Symfony 5.4, it does not work that easily with runtime version

Comment: Okay.  Now I understand what you are trying to do.  Sticking with the original index.php is probably your best bet.  I did open a [Symfony discussion](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions/46753) for this topic.  The docs really should be updated.

Answer (score 1):

So the task is to migrate from a non-Symfony legacy app to a Symfony app.  The basic idea is to allow the Symfony app to process a request and then hand it off to the legacy app if necessary.  The [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/migration.html#front-controller-with-legacy-bridge) show how to do this but but relies on the older style index.php file.  The newer runtime based approach is a bit different.

But in the end all it really takes is a couple of fairly simple classes.  A runner class takes care of creating a request object and turning it into a response.  This is where you can add the bridge to your legacy app.  It's a clone of Symfony's HttpKernelRunner class:

```
namespace App\Legacy;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\TerminableInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Runtime\RunnerInterface;

class LegacyRunner implements RunnerInterface
{
    private $kernel;
    private $request;

    public function __construct(HttpKernelInterface $kernel, Request $request)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function run(): int
    {
        $response = $this->kernel->handle($this->request);

        // check the response to see if it should be handed off to legacy app
        dd('Response Code ' . $response->getStatusCode());

        $response->send();

        if ($this->kernel instanceof TerminableInterface) {
            $this->kernel->terminate($this->request, $response);
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Next you need to wire up runner by extending the SymfonyRuntime::getRunner method:

```
namespace App\Legacy;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Runtime\RunnerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Runtime\SymfonyRuntime;

class LegacyRuntime extends SymfonyRuntime
{
  public function getRunner(?object $application): RunnerInterface
  {
      if ($application instanceof HttpKernelInterface) {
          return new LegacyRunner($application, Request::createFromGlobals());
      }
      return parent::getRunner($application);
  }
}
```

Finally, update composer.json to use your legacy runtime class:

```
   "extra": {
        ...
        "runtime": {
            "class": "App\\Legacy\\LegacyRuntime"
        }
    }
```

After updating composer.json do a `composer update` for the changes to take effect and start your server. Navigate to a route and you should hit the dd statement.