# Return value from index.php

Tags: php, symfony

I have installed a symfony app skeleton using 2 composer commands as advised from symfony.com/doc

*file: index.php*

```
<?php

use App\Kernel;

require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';

return function (array $context) {
    return new Kernel($context['APP_ENV'], (bool) $context['APP_DEBUG']);
};
```

*snippets from file: autoload_runtime.php*

```
<?php
if (true === (require_once __DIR__.'/autoload.php') || empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) {
    return;
}

...

[$app, $args]= ...

...

exit(
    $runtime
        ->getRunner($app)
        ->run()
);
```

So the return statement in index.php gets thread of execution dependt on some condition.

What handles something returned from the main script. It looks like a callback that some runtime (in mod_php?) not only calls but also can do something with, with the returned object.

Comment: index.php used to be much easier to understand before the runtime component was added in 5.2.  You might want to install a 4.4 app and take a peak.  In any event the Runner class is where the real work takes place.  Take a look at the code.  It is also straightforward to use your own runner if you want something different. [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72720833/install-symfony-without-symfony-runtime-and-with-old-index-php/72734128#72734128).

Comment: Thanks - I appreciates the hint of version dependt index.php and will try a 4.4 app

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you in anyway, but here's a general breakdown of what's going on.

But before that, `return`, `include` and their `_once` versions are strange language constructs, and not really functions, and what they really do is sometimes weird and unexpected. You kind of have to read through the [man page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) on it to get a full understanding, and even then there's some surprises I think.

In `autoload_runtime.php`, the following code's job is to guard against accidentally booting things twice (or possibly a missing server variable) because the `require_once` function will return `true` if the called file has already be included already.

```php
if (true === (require_once __DIR__.'/autoload.php') || empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) {
    return;
}
```

Then the following line re-loads the `index.php` (or whatever the file is called) which is the clever part:

```
$app = require $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
```

Because `autoload_runtime.php` was brought in using `require_once` it is skipped and just the function is returned which is set to the `$app` variable. The function, *when invoked* actually boots the kernel, however that happens a little bit later.

(One clever aspect of returning a closure that boots the kernel is that `Kernel` isn't event type-checked until the closure is invoked. You can see that [here](https://3v4l.org/DgZaU) where nothing is thrown for a class that doesn't exist.)

If you `var_dump($app)` at that point you'd see a normal closure.

Then finally a runtime which depends on how you installed the Symfony is instantiated, the `$app` closure is actually invoked returning a Kernel, the runtime "runs" and the final result is past to `exit` which is universally used for all PHP SAPIs to give a status code.

The "runtime runs" might involve looking at `$_SERVER` variables to determine the route, etc.

Comment: Thank you - it was help full - I had to read the answer several times because there is a lot in it. I can see now that the return is a return from an, by the require function, included index.php - I consider a return in index.php at top 'stack trace' thread of execution is without any other effect than normal termination. Awesome [PHP shell](https://3v4l.org)