# How to overwrite symfony autoload_runtime

Tags: php, symfony

I need to add a function to `index.php` just after the response was sent to the browser.

In the old symfony it was simple, all I had to do was to add my code between those lines:

```
$response->send();
// My function here
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

But now symfony completely redesigned their `index.php` file
and most of the code is located in a generated `/vendor/autoload_runtime.php`

So I have to replace

```
exit(
    $runtime
        ->getRunner($app)
        ->run()
);
```

with

```
$response = $runtime->getRunner($app)->run();
// My function here
exit($response);
```

But how can I do this?
`autoload_runtime.php` is in gitignore.
And even if I modify it directly on the server, it seems to be getting reverted randomly.

Comment: What kind of function are you trying to add ? I'm curious if you really need to do so

Comment: I am trying to log request time and total memory usage of each endpoint (excluding the terminate).
`file_put_contents('request.log', sprintf("%s  % 8.3f MB % 8.3f MB % 10.3f ms  %s\n", date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1048576, memory_get_peak_usage(false) / 1048576, 1000 * (microtime(true) - $start), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: It might be overkill but it's actually not that hard to [make your own runner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72720833/install-symfony-without-symfony-runtime-and-with-old-index-php/72734128#72734128).  Or maybe I should say it's not that hard after you have done it once.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section. Why not add a TerminateEventListener with highest priority? This would get called as the first one, before all other events that Symfony itself ships